# gdal_translate: unknown displacement after transformation

Tags: gdal, coordinates, modis, netcdf, hdf

I am new to GDAL and after a lot of research I cannot find a solution to my problem.

I want to extract a Scientific DataSet (SDS) from an HDF file, but when I do this with gdal_translate there is a small displacement of the netCDF data compared to the original HDF data. Can someone explain to me why this happens and how to solve it?

I am using Panoply to view the data.

Original file: MCD18A1.A2020153.h17v05.006.2020201050502.hdf

Panoply view of the original file: [image: Image of Original HDF file]

I removed the SDS from the original HDF file to a netCDF using the following command:

```
gdal_translate -of netCDF -co "FORMAT=NC4" HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD18A1.A2020153.h17v05.006.2020201050502.hdf":MODISRAD:GMT_1200_DSR OUTPUT.nc
```

Panoply view (It can be seen that the raster has shifted slightly):

[image: Image of netCDF file]

Using `-a_ullr <ulx> <uly> <lrx> <lry>` I verified that the displacement is ~2000, but why this value?

Comment: What does `gdalinfo HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD18A1.A2020153.h17v05.006.2020201050502.hdf":MODISRAD:GMT_1200_DSR` report about pixel size and AREA_OR_POIT metadata?

Comment: Hi user30184, 

Pixel Size = (4633.127165279166547, -4633.127165279166547) according to gdalinfo.
The MCD18A1 product documentation states that the data is provided with a pixel size of 5600m.
I didn't find anything about AREA_OR_POINT in the output of gdalinfo.
Do you want me to attach the full gdalinfo output?

Comment: Sorry, AREA_OR_POINT belongs to GeoTIFF. I do not know how georeferencing is stored into HDF and it seems to be generally fuzzy https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hdf4.html. I fear I can't help you with this.